# Composing integral transforms means multiplying the kernels.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, integral-transforms

The exercise I'm working with is 2.1.6(b) in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis* (2/e):

> Let $(X,\,\Omega,\,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $k_1$, $k_2$ be two kernels satisfying
> \begin{equation}
> \int_X |k_i(x,\,y)|\,d\mu(y) \le c_1 \quad \text{a.e.}[\mu],\\
> \int_X |k_i(x,\,y)|\,d\mu(x) \le c_2 \quad \text{a.e.}[\mu].
> \end{equation}
> Define
> $$
> k:X \times X \to \mathbb F \quad \text{by} \quad
> k(x,\,y) = \int_X k_1(x,\,z) \, k_2(z,\,y)\,d\mu(z).
> $$
> (a) Show that $k$ also satisfies the same hypothesis as $k_1$ and $k_2$.
> (b) If $K$, $K_1$, $K_2$ are the integral operators with kernels $k$, $k_1$, $k_2$, show that $K=K_1K_2$.

The author defines the integral transform by:
$$
(Kf)(x) := \int_X k(x,\,y)\,f(y)\,d\mu(y).
$$

So easily I solved (a),
with $c_i^2$ in the places of $c_i$.
I think I also done with (b),
but I'm not sure my solution is correct.
So please be kind to check whether it is fine or not.
A better idea or a more concise solution will always be appreciated.

**My solution**:
We first show that the integral
$$
I(x) =
\int_X |k_1(x,\,z)|
\int_X |k_2(z,\,y)| \cdot |f(y)|
\,d\mu(y) \,d\,u(z)
$$
is finite for almost all $x$.
Use Hölder's inequality for the integrand $\sqrt{|k_2(z,\,y)|} \cdot \sqrt{|k_2(z,\,y)|}|f(y)|$ to get
$$
\int_X |k_2(z,\,y)| \cdot \left| f(y) \right| \,d\mu(y)
\quad\le\quad
\left( \int_X |k_2(z,\,y)| \,d\mu(y) \right)^{1/2}
\left( \int_X |k_2(z,\,y)| \cdot |f(y)|^2 \,d\mu(y) \right)^{1/2}.
$$
Then we have
$$
I(x)
\quad\le\quad
\sqrt{c_1}
\int_X |k_1(x,\,z)|
\left(
\int_X |k_2(z,\,y)| \cdot |f(y)|^2 \,d\mu(y)
\right)^{1/2}
\,d\mu(z).
$$
The similar Hölder argument for $\sqrt{k_1}$ gives
$$
I(x)
\quad\le\quad
c_1
\left(
\int_X |k_1(x,\,z)|
\int_X |k_2(z,\,y)| \cdot |f(y)|^2
\,d\mu(y)
\,d\mu(z)
\right)^{1/2}
$$
So we may estimate the $L^2$-norm of $I$ as follows:
$$
\|I\|^2
\quad\le\quad
{c_1} ^2
\int_X
\int_X
\int_X
|k_1(x,\,z)| \cdot |k_2(z,\,y)| \cdot |f(y)|^2
\,d\mu(y)
\,d\mu(z)
\,d\mu(x).
$$
But Fubini's theorem allows changing the order of the integrals. Hence
$$
\text{(RHS)} \quad = \quad
{c_1} ^2
\int_X
\int_X
\int_X
|k_1(x,\,z)| \cdot |k_2(z,\,y)| \cdot |f(y)|^2
\,d\mu(x)
\,d\mu(z)
\,d\mu(y)
\quad\le\quad
{c_1}^2 {c_2}^2 \|f\|^2
$$
by the assumptions on the kernels.

Since $\|I\| < \infty$, we have
$$
\int_X
\int_X
|k_1(x,\,z)| \cdot |k_2(z,\,y)| \cdot |f(y)|
\,d\mu(y)
\,d\mu(z)
\quad < \quad
\infty
$$
for almost all $x$. Hence by the Fubini's theorem we justify the change of the order of integrals to conclude that
\begin{align}
(K_1 K_2 f)(x)
=&
\int_X
\int_X
k_1(x,\,z) \, k_2(z,\,y) \, f(y)
\,d\mu(y)
\,d\mu(z)
\\
=&
\int_X
\int_X
k_1(x,\,z) \, k_2(z,\,y) \, f(y)
\,d\mu(z)
\,d\mu(y)
\\
=&
(Kf)(x)
\end{align}
holds for almost all $x$.